# How to create text field placeholder text that changes whenever viewcontroller is entered

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm utilizing swift and I was wondering if it would be possible to essentially loop though placeholder text for a UITextField. In other words, is it possible to show a different placeholder text value each time the user enters the viewcontroller that contains the said text field?

Comment: Yes. What problem are you running into?

Comment: @jtbandes Well, I tried implementing it, but I ran into some issues randomizing the data.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific to get a good answer here — what exactly have you tried? What specific problems have you hit? See the [help] and [ask] in particular.

Comment: Are you asking how to set the placeholder text for UITextField?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your text field's placeholder text in the `viewWillAppear` lifecycle method of your View Controller.

Below is a contrived example of how you would do that for a text field called `yourTextField`. Each time the view appears, the placeholder text is updated with the current date.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let randomPlaceholderText = "\(NSDate())"
        yourTextField.placeholder = randomPlaceholderText
    }
 }
```

As the name implies, the `viewWillAppear` method is called right before the view will appear.